# Linux Apache in Sleep State

Tags: php, linux, apache, unix

I have a Linux Ubuntu server having Apache2 that runs PHP.
All of a sudden my website gets error:

```
404 Not Found: The requested URL / was not found on this server
```

I tried:

```
sudo service apache2 status
```

Result:

```
Apache2 is running (pid 1546)
```

So I tried:

```
cat /proc/1546/status
```

Result:

```
State: S(sleeping)
```

Apache error.log file:

```
[Fri Jul 24 05:22:46 2015] [error] [client 155.124.123.161] File does not exist: /etc/apache2/htdocs
```

My question is, is this maybe the reason why my Apache server is not working properly that I get Not Found error? Is Sleep state of Apache a problem and what should I do about it? My website codes is in path /var/www/mywebapplication. It is working for a very long time but suddenly it gets error.

Thank you very much.

Comment: think SO is not the right place to ask this...

Comment: does the directory /etc/apache2/htdocs (still)  exists?

Comment: Hi @BigMike, /etc/apache2/htdocs doesn't exist. I'm not sure if it exists before as the applications are deployed in /var/www/ folder. thanks.

Comment: then check Apache config and verify www root isn't pointing at /etc/apache2/htdocs

Comment: I have found file: /etc/apache2/apache2.conf. While httpd.conf doesn't contain anything. apache2.conf doesn't contain DocumentRoot. Where can I find if its pointing to htdocs or www folder? thanks.

Comment: This may be an issue with older versions of mod_php. I have experienced this exact issue before, where php files suddenly return a 404 instead of mod_php running the script. Try updating your version of both httpd and mod_php to the latest available version (or use PHP-FPM) and see if that solves it.